# React tag script are called only the first time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, script-tag

I'm trying to add a script on my react component, and this script must be called each time the component is rendered..

This is an example :

```
var ReactComponent = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var html = '<script>console.log("A")</script>';
    console.log("B");

    return (
        <div>
          <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: html}} />
        </div>
    );
  }
});
```

But when I look on my console, with for example 3 render of this component i got :

```
B 
A // Logged the first render
B // Now, only the 'B' is called.
B
```

Instead of

```
B 
A // Log A every time
B 
A // Log A every time
B 
A // Log A every time
```

Comment: The content isn't changing, and so React is skipping changing the real DOM. `render` is called each time, but the `<script>` in the document is not being rewritten. This is by design.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, React only outputs changes to the DOM when content changes between renders. As your script tag never changes, it will never be called again.

How much control do you have on the script tag element? If you are writing the script tag out directly in a string, as in your question, you could add a random number to the element which would cause React re-render each time `render` is called:

```
var ReactComponent = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var randomId = Math.random();
    var html = '<script data-id="'+ randomId +'">console.log("A")</script>';
    console.log("B");

    return (
        <div>
          <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: html}} />
        </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

wouldn't just executing the script be sufficient? For example with eval().

Comment: On this example yes maybe, but it's a script tag with a src attribut, who load a file :/